# Check if string is made up from random number/letter combinations

Tags: c#, .net

Is it somehow possible to tell two strings apart if let's say one looks like this:

"Hello I am a new user how are you all"
and
"U77agh gh78ah92v192v 9181v 72b"

I want to get rid of spammers, but I'm not sure how I would detect if the string is good or bad.

Thanks.

Comment: You could comprise a list of adverbs : is, am, are, was, were, have, has, had, do, does, did, shall, will, may, might, can, could. And check to see if the sentence contains any of the these.  But that's not going to get rid of spammers. Spammers can construct even half way decent sentence stuctures. Your best bet is to disallow linking and confirm registration, if its a site you're working on.

Comment: You could implement a method like reCAPTCHA or even just a simple math problem that users would have to fill out to post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first use a captcha to detect bots from users.

And then, I would use something like Google Translate API to see if the string translates into other languages. If it can't translate the string, it looks like it will return the same string and if the string doesn't translate in 5 languages then for sure there's something wrong with it. You could probably refine this by splitting the string in words to see if you're not getting *"This looks like a good string but U77agh gh78ah92v192v"* and if all or nearly all the words translate then you've probably got a clean string.

Comment: Captcha doesn't work in this case. But the translate thing is very clever. It would be better with a local solution, but the google translate it probably a better solution in the end.